How is $\mathbb{Z}/\ell\mathbb{Z}$ a module over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$?
I have a fundamental question concerning the definition of $\ell$-adic étale cohomology.
It is defined as
$$H^{n}(X,\mathbb{Q}_{\ell})=\lim_{\leftarrow m}H^{n}(X,\mathbb{Z}/\ell^{m}\mathbb{Z})\otimes \mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$$
How can $\mathbb{Z}/\ell^{m}\mathbb{Z}$ be viewed as a module over $X$ if $X$ is defined over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ and $p\neq\ell$?

It’s just a sheaf of abelian groups.

For more details see the lecture notes on Etale Cohomology by J.S. Milne.

$\Bbb Z/\ell^m\Bbb Z$ in this context is the constant sheaf of abelian groups on $X$ with value $\Bbb Z/\ell^m\Bbb Z$; there is no need for $\Bbb Z/\ell^m\Bbb Z$ to be a module over $\Bbb F_p$ (and indeed it is not such a module unless $\ell=p$ and $m=1$, or $m=0$).

Ah, shoot, beaten in the comments while I was writing this post.
